# R Image Colorbreak & colors

Tags: image, r, colors

in an R image I'm trying to change the breaks and color, when the value of my image is above 20 It has to stay red. (in my current case it becomes white)

```
  colors <- colorpanel(30, "green","red")
  colbreaks <- seq(1,20, length=length(colors)+1)
```

using the colorpanel from gplot to use the colors green and red.
My values are mostly 1-15, sometimes higher than 20, but because I want to keep the difference visible, I want to make 20 the limit. In my script, when the value is 21 or higher the square becomes white. How can I catch this so it stays red?
reproduce:

```
test123 <- structure(c(2,7,3,18,22,25,12,1), .Dim = c(2L,4L))  
colors <- colorpanel(30, "green","red")  
colbreaks <- seq(1,20, length=length(colors)+1)
image(test123, col=colors, breaks=colbreaks)
```

[image]
the two white squares in the image are of the values 22 and 25.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define also the last break point (25). This should work:

```
test123 <- structure(c(2,7,3,18,22,25,12,1), .Dim = c(2L,4L))  
colors <- colorpanel(20, "green","red")  
colbreaks <- c(seq(1,20, length=length(colors)),max(test123)) #add the last point
image(test123, col=colors, breaks=colbreaks)
```

Here everything between 20 and `max(test123)` are colored with same color (last value from `colors`).

Comment: Thank you, I used a static value instead of the Max of the values, and got it working! thanks